# How to convert a Dr.Java project to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Could someone tell me how to import my Java program code to eclipse? Because im kinda confused with trying to import it. I generally use Dr. Java but I want to start using eclipse as i feel its more professional and i like the "feel" of it? So could someone explain to me how to go about doing this?

If you need anything just ask :D

Comment: Just create a new project in Eclipse and import the Java source.

Comment: @MattBall how do i import it?

Comment: not sure why people voted down on my question, i was an question that I did not know the answer till someone answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to import your code into Eclipse:

- Ensure all your code is under a single folder (e.g. /project)
- In Eclipse use File -> New -> Java Project

You will be prompted for the following:

- Project Name - this is what it will be called in Eclipse (e.g. Foo)
- JRE - choose the same as you were using in Dr Java
- Project layout - create separate folders for source/class files.

This will create your project.

Next import the source:

- RClick on your new project (Foo) and click Import... -> General -> File System
- Select the folder containing your code (/project)
- Tick the resources you want to import (or the folder to import everything)

This will copy the code from your original location (/project) into your Eclipse project (located in your workspace)

Answer (score 0):

You can import projects into the eclipse work space as file systems. Try exporting your project from Dr. Java as a file system, and import that into eclipse.

Comment: how? sorry im so confused.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can import DrJava project into Eclipse. Try to create a new Java project instead. In the New Java Project dialog box, uncheck "Use default location" checkbox and enter the path to your existing source code.